# How does React's setState() preserve immutability?

Tags: reactjs, state, variable-assignment, setstate

In the [tutorial on React's site](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), the following code is given and a moment is taken to discuss immutability.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

> ... We suggested that you use the .slice() method to create a copy of the squares array to modify instead of modifying the existing array. The end result is the same but by not mutating (or changing the underlying data) directly, we gain several benefits

With a language like `C#` and the immutable reference type of `string`, when we "mutate" a `string`, we're really creating a brand new `string` object and putting in a reference somewhere depending on the string assignment. For example,

```
// C#
string squares1 = "xyz";
string squares2 = "abc";
squares1 = squares2;
```

would result in squares1 holding a reference to the data pointed at by squares2.

So what's happening under the hood with `setState()`? I am especially curious since it is stated that a history of values for an object is preserved?

Comment: React is open source, if you're curious about implementation details you can always [examine the implementation itself](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/393924879fbba20e43d9de76f9fb4f01c945cefa/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L58). Is there a specific detail of setState that you're curious about?

Comment: Note that the title question is a bit misleading. `setState` itself does not preserve immutability; rather, you are encouraged to _use_ it immutably.